# Which is the appropriate way to test for a dictionary type?

Tags: python, dictionary, isinstance

Why are there so many different ways to test for a dictionary?
And what would be the most modern way to test if an object is a dictionary?

```
adict = {'a': 1}

In [10]: isinstance(adict, types.DictType)
Out[10]: True

In [11]: isinstance(adict, types.DictionaryType)
Out[11]: True

In [12]: isinstance(adict, dict)
Out[12]: True

In [13]: isinstance(adict, collections.Mapping)
Out[13]: True

In [14]: isinstance(adict, collections.MutableMapping)
Out[14]: True
```

Comment: The same could be said of most built-in types in Python.

Comment: Either for legacy support or syntactic-sugar?

Comment: The last three all test for different but related things. Why is it so surprising in a language where everything is an object which supports multiple inheritance that built-in types can test true for several variations of `isinstance`?

Comment: there are languages whose collections library is way more sophisticated and consists of far finer grained interfaces than Python's, for example Scala's `scala.collection` is an extreme (but nice) example.

Comment: @user2864740: I think you changed the question title to something that the OP did not mean; it's a big difference to ask "what's the right way" and "why are there so many different ways".

Comment: @ErikAllik Perhaps. The OP can revert it if he/she so wishes. I was working with the goal of eliminating the question begging an opinion. That being said, I agree that it does. I've added back in the original "title question" in the body itself.

Comment: I don't think the "why" is opinion based here; there are concrete reasons for the plurality of options and there's not much room for opinion. And I think the original question title was much more interesting/important.

Answer (score 11):

`types.DictType` and `types.DictionaryType` are deprecated (well, removed in Python 3) aliases of `dict`.

`collections.Mapping` and `collections.MutableMapping` are *Abstract* Base Classes (ABCs) so they work with mappings that don't subclass from `dict`. Normally that makes them a better choice, although very occasionally the stricter typecheck will be helpful.

So basically, check against, in order

- None of them, if possible (duck-type)
- `collections.Mapping` if you don't need mutation
- `collections.MutableMapping` if you do need mutation
- `dict` if you need it to *actually be* a `dict` type (this should be rare)
- `types.DictType` or `types.DictionaryType` if you want to support *really old* versions

Comment: For the sake of being explicit about what "*really old* versions" means - `isinstance(x, dict)` has worked since the introduction of new-style classes in Python 2.2, which was released in December 2001.

Answer (score 2):

First, `types.DictType`, `types.DictionaryType`, and `dict` are all the same (the documentation effectively notes that the first two are aliases for `dict`).

The last two are abstract base classes, and will actually test `True` for objects that don't inherit from `dict` at all. These are used if you want to test if an object is *dict-like*, i.e. whether it implements the same sort of operations that `dict` would. They are slightly different: `Mapping` is for general mappings (that may be immutable), whereas `MutableMapping` is strictly for mappings that can be modified.